# Angular4: How to mock return value of 2 http calls called in sequence

Tags: angular

I have a function that makes 2 sequential HTTP calls - the second call is made depending on the result of the first call. How can I mock both calls correctly when unit testing?

component.ts

```
getValue(): Promise<any[]> {
    return this.http.get(URL1).toPromise()   // FIRST CALL
        .then(data => {
            this.enable = data.json()['enable'];
        })
        .then(() => {
            if (this.enable) {
                return new Promise<any[]>((resolve) => {
                    this.http.get(URL2).toPromise()  // SECOND CALL
                        .then(res => res.json()));
                });
            }
        })
        .catch(() => {
            return new Promise<any[]>((resolve) => resolve([]));
        });
}
```

component.spec.ts

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpModule],
        providers: [...]
    });
    service = TestBed.get(...);
    http = TestBed.get(Http);
});

it('getValue works as expected when call succeeds',() => {
    spyOn(http, 'get').and.returnValue(of({enable: true}));  // return of firstcall
    spyOn(http, 'get').and.returnValue(of(RAW_DATA));  // return of second call
    service.getValue ('uuid')
        .then(data => {
            expect(data).toEqual(expectedData);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should return the first value given for the first call and the second value for the second call.

```
spyOn(http, 'get').and.returnValues(of({enable: true}), of(RAW_DATA));
```